# Need to replace siding after deck removal, rim joist is exposed

Tags: foundation, siding, decking

Ripped out a deck to install a patio.  The deck was attached directly to the rim joist(idk?) And now it's exposed.  Do I need to put anything over it or can I simply install a replacement piece of siding? Thank you all in advance [image: exposed rim joist and mudsill]

Comment: What you are calling a rim joist is probably a ledger. If you removed a rim joist, you'd be in a heap of doo. I suspect you can build out the existing gap with sheathing and insulation to match the depth of existing wall, and then align new siding lap, paint it, and call it good.

Comment: When I add this additional wood to bump out in line with the rest, should I put any wrap on it or tape the seam?